# Can I control the position of an uploaded document on firebase?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, document

I need to know if there is a way to control the document position on firebase with flutter, like if the app uploaded sth, it will be on top cause it will really help me, thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want documents in Firestore to have an order, you will need to populate a field that defines the order.  Firestore does not keep track of any ordering for you.

If you want to use the time that a document was added to the collection to define its order in the collection, consider using a [server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp), and use that timestamp to order your queries.

Comment: ok, the only problem that I may face is that I name my documents with index, so if a user added a document it will go up as you said, but how can I change the index of the whole collections' documents ?

Comment: You will have to iterate and update each document individually.

Comment: it's ok now, I won't need server timestamp as firebase already arrange the documents in index, the only problem is how to change the index of the documents.

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately along with the code you have that isn't working the way you expect.  Or explain what you're stuck on.

Comment: Just did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64149652/how-can-i-change-the-index-name-of-documents-in-firebase-as-i-upload-a-document)